# Carousel Videos Youtube

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net

tengo el siguiente desafio. 
Debo hacer un correlativo de vídeos que estan en youtube, los cuales deben ir cambiando cada vez que se cargue la pagina. Intente hacerlo con un carousel slide pero no me funciona.

```html
 <asp:Panel ID="panVideosEme" Visible="false" runat="server">
                        <div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblVideos" Font-Bold="true" Style="color: #1B406D; font-weight: bold; font-size:large" runat="server">Nuestro EME</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <Video  Style="border: 2px solid black; width:100%; height:100%;" alt="First slide" ID="mp4_anden"  controls="controls"></Video>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

```
Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
mp4_anden = "~/images/Videos/Vid" + rand.Next(1, 6).ToString() + ".mp4";
```

Comment: Vas a hacer la página bien pesada... ¿Segura que quieres poner video?

Comment: si tienes razón, tengo tb los videos en youtube. Pero necesito que cada vez que se refresque la pagina cargue los 6 videos que tengo. Tienes alguna idea de como hacerlo? te lo agradecería bastante

Answer (score 0):

Tu etiqueta video esta mal formulada. Debe quedar algo así:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="panVideosEme" Visible="false" runat="server">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <asp:Label ID="lblVideos" Font-Bold="true" Style="color: #1B406D; font-weight: bold; font-size:large" runat="server">Nuestro EME</asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <Video  Style="border: 2px solid black; width:100%; height:100%;" alt="First slide" controls="controls">
<source src="mp4_anden" type="video/mp4">
</Video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Puedes especificar de manera rápida también sin agregar la etiqueta source, algo así:

```
<video style="border: 2px solid black; width:100%; height:100%;" src="mp4_anden" width="640" height="480" controls></video>
```

¿Por que se usa la etiqueta source? Pues cuando los navegador no aceptan un tipo de video, puedes tener varias extensiones.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Su navegador no soporta ninguna extensión de video (de las agregadas).
</video>
```

Pulso y suerte Camila !

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Maikel Yordan!!!